# how to walk through the entire array (we have the form of a tree) and wait for the result?

Tags: javascript

how to walk through the entire array (we have the form of a tree) and wait for the result?
there is an array

```
    arr=[  {
        "id": ,
        "name": "",
        "url": "",
        "childs": [
          {
            "id": ,
            "parent": ,
            "name": "",
            "url": "",
"childs":[{}{}],
},
     {
            "id": ,
            "parent": ,
            "name": "",
            "url": "",}]
```

an element can have child elements, and they still have children.

```
   for (const cat of arr) {

  if (cat['childs']) {
    for (const child of cat['childs']) {
      if (!child['childs']) {
        const category_name = child['name'];
        const category_url = child['url'];


    categoryes.push({
      category_name: category_name,
      category_url: category_url,
    });
  } else {
    for (const sub_child of child['childs']) {
      if (!sub_child['childs']) {
        const category_name = sub_child['name'];
        const category_url = sub_child['url'];
        const shard = sub_child['shard'];
        const query = sub_child['query'];
        categoryes.push({
          category_name: category_name,
          category_url: category_url,
      
        });
      } else {
        for (const sub_child2 of sub_child['childs']) {
          if (!sub_child2['childs']) {
            const category_name = sub_child2['name'];
            const category_url = sub_child2['url'];
          
            categoryes.push({
              category_name: category_name,
              category_url: category_url,
           
            });
          } else {
            for (const sub_child3 of sub_child2['childs']) {
              console.log(sub_child3);
              if (sub_child3['childs']) {
                console.log(sub_child3);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

but I do not know how many nested elements there can be. How to go through all and wait for the result?

Comment: do you have some data, the result (real and wanted) and the error, you get?

Comment: Is the nesting structure always the same? That is to say, do all of the children elements have the `id`,`parent`,`name`, `url`, and `childs` keys? **EDIT** If they do, you might be able to use recursion, and to pass the `categoreys` object by reference, so it gets filled up to the end.

Answer (score 2):

using recursion like this might help you :-

```js
let categoryes = [];

function walkEntireArray(arr){
 arr.forEach(element => {
    if(typeof element["childs"] !== 'undefined') {
        walkEntireArray(childs) 
    }
    const category_name = element['name'];
    const category_url = element['url'];
    categoryes.push({
        category_name: category_name,
        category_url: category_url,
    
      });
 });
}
```

Comment: Avoid link-only answers. What would happen if the site in question goes down, or changes its structure? It would be better if you post the code as the answer, and leave the link for reference.

Comment: Some modifications are needed for this to work. First, `walkEntireArray` should be defined as a function - just add `function` in front of `walkEntireArray`. Second, change the checkup in your if to be like this `if(typeof element["childs"] !== 'undefined')`, to avoid errors. Third, and this is just a suggestion, you could add a test case, with logging the results to the console, just so it's obvious the code is working as intended.